# Difference between CBOW and SKIP Gram word vectors

Tags: word-embeddings, word2vec

I have gone through several links but was not able to understand how `CBOW and Skip Gram` is trained from scratch?

Any good link/blogs or books would be very helpful.

[Word2Vec - CBOW and Skip-Grams](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/19654/word2vec-cbow-and-skip-grams)

What's the difference between `Skipgram word2vec` and `CBOW word2vec` during training and when to use CBOW Skip-gram. ?

`Example or Application where CBOW would be preferable choice but not Skip-gram and vice versa.`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a example for what @Christos Karatsalos is [describing](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/82927/105740):

If you take a statement like "The cat jumped over the puddle",

In `CBOW`'s case, the neural network's word embeddings are trained by passing a input `set of words` to the neural network and making the network to predict an output `word` as shown below:

$\{ cat, jumped, over, the, puddle\} \rightarrow  The $

$\{ The, jumped, over, the, puddle\} \rightarrow  cat $

$\{ The, cat, over, the, puddle\} \rightarrow  jumped $

$\{ cat, jumped, the, puddle\} \rightarrow  over $

$\{ The, cat, jumped, over, puddle\} \rightarrow  the $

$\{ The, cat, jumped, over, the\} \rightarrow  puddle $

In `skip-gram`'s case, the neural network's word embeddings are trained by passing an input `word` to the neural network and teaching the network to predict a `set of words` as shown below:

$The \rightarrow  \{ cat, jumped, over, the, puddle\} $

$cat \rightarrow \{ The, jumped, over, the, puddle\}$

$jumped \rightarrow  \{ The, cat, over, the, puddle\}$

$over \rightarrow  \{ cat, jumped, the, puddle\}$

$the \rightarrow  \{ The, cat, jumped, over, puddle\}$

$puddle \rightarrow \{ The, cat, jumped, over, the\}$

For usage, if you are thinking of a fill-in-the-blanks kind of problem `CBOW Word2Vec` would be a suitable vector to use, on the other hand if you have a word and you are trying to come up with a new sentence with it then   `skip-gram Word2Vec` will be useful.

Take a look this lecture [notes](http://cs224d.stanford.edu/lecture_notes/notes1.pdf) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

CBOW model is able to learn to predict the word by the context, which means that it tries to maximize the probability of the target word by looking at the context. On the other hand, the Skip-gram model is designed to predict the context given the word.

Skip-gram model works well with small amount of training data, moreover it represents well even rare words or phrases.

CBOW model is several times faster to train than the Skip-gram model, and achieves slightly better accuracy for the frequent words.

Comment: Why Skip-gram model works well with small amount of training data?

Comment: According to the following paper, Skip-gram works well with small amount of the training data.

Comment: Tomas Mikolov, Ilya Sutskever, Kai Chen, Gregory S. Corrado, and Jeffrey Dean. 2013b. Distributed representations of words and phrases and their compositionality. In Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems 26: 27th Annual Conference on Neural Information Processing Systems 2013. Proceedings of a meeting held December 5-8, 2013, Lake Tahoe, Nevada, United States, pages 3111–3119.